# textarea auto expand

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this auto expand textarea jquery code and currently, it is working somehow there except for Google Chrome.

The issue is when I added the style padding:3px to the textarea, whenever I type something in the box, it will expand the height. If I remove the style padding, it will work nicely.

The test is here: (Use Google Chrome to test)

```js
(function($) {

    // jQuery plugin definition
    $.fn.TextAreaExpander = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
        var hCheck = !($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera);

        // resize a textarea
        function ResizeTextarea(e) {
            // event or initialize element?
            e = e.target || e;

            // find content length and box width
            var vlen = e.value.length, ewidth = e.offsetWidth;
            if( vlen != e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth ) {
                $("#msg").html(e.boxWidth);
                if( hCheck && (vlen < e.valLength || ewidth != e.boxWidth) ) e.style.height = "0px";
                var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight, e.expandMax));

                e.style.overflow = (e.scrollHeight > h ? "auto" : "hidden");
                e.style.height = h + "px";
                e.valLength = vlen;
                e.boxWidth = ewidth;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // initialize
        this.each(function( ) {
            // is a textarea?
            if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase( ) != "textarea") return;

            // set height restrictions
            var p = this.className.match(/expand(\d+)\-*(\d+)*/i);
            this.expandMin = minHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[1], 10) : 0);
            this.expandMax = maxHeight || (p ? parseInt('0'+p[2], 10) : 99999);

            // initial resize
            ResizeTextarea(this);

            // zero vertical padding and add events
            if (!this.Initialized) {
                this.Initialized = true;
                //$(this).css("padding-top", 0).css("padding-bottom", 0);
                $(this).bind("keyup", ResizeTextarea)
                       .bind("focus", ResizeTextarea)
                       .bind("input", ResizeTextarea);
            }
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready( function( ) {
    $("#message").TextAreaExpander(40);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.textfield {
    padding:3px 3px;
    width:98%;
}
</style>
<textarea id="message" class="expand textfield"></textarea>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

I have been trying to figure out why, would appreciate if anyone could shed some light here.

Comment: Why are you using the length of value? Shouldn't you be counting lines instead?

Comment: Not sure though, this is a plugin I got somewhere.

Comment: Not directly related: You are expanding indefinitely. This may cause some annoyance. you may want to consider expanding only till a certain point and then add scrollbars.

Comment: There is a e.expandMax which I can fine tune it though. But yeah, maybe at a later date if this should have any issue. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to write a code that sets the height when content changed. Unfortunately, if I put padding, I get the same behavior on Google Chrome: `$('#MyTextArea').css('height',document.getElementById('MyTextArea').scrollHeight + 'px');`

Comment: Thanks domanokz, can this be a bug in Chrome then? Possible to add in some hack to solve it?

Comment: I think in order to solve this I would have to manually track Webkit browser and set padding to 0 for them...arg :(

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you use this plugin instead:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer

StackOverflow uses this plugin for its textareas! Do I have to say more?

Hope this helps. Cheers

PS: Or, you could use the [autogrow plugin](http://javascriptly.com/examples/jquery-grab-bag/autogrow-textarea.html)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Edgar. Firstly I needed something like auto expand so the stackovflw resizer is not my choice. Moreover alot of the latest browsers now automatically support resizer to textarea, hence the plugin is kind of redundant.

Secondly I have seen and tried lots of plugin, alot of them usually leaves an extra spacing at the bottom of your text when you type. The plugin I posted is by far the best for my case.

Answer (score 0):

So sad that you asked 4 years ago and I just saw it.

The issue happens because the scrollHeight property returns the entire height of an element in pixels; including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin. (At least in Chrome, IE and Firefox, these three I have tested).

Ref: [Element Scroll Height](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollheight.asp)

So I changed `line 17` in your Jsfiddle as below, and problem solved.

```
var h = Math.max(e.expandMin, Math.min(e.scrollHeight - 6, e.expandMax));
```